# How to have same size of objects in different screen resolutions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity. I'm developing it for android and it's in portrait mode. I have placed one wall on left side of screen and one wall on right side of screen. The problem is the distance between those 2 walls is different in different screen resolutions. So, my character can't jump from one wall to other with the same velocity being applied.
I'm attaching an image to make my point clear.[image: Comparison]

What can I do so that in different devices, I get the same distance between these 2 walls? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is how I'm placing the walls right now.

```
screenLeft = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f)).x;
screenRight = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.width, 0f, 0f)).x;

rightWallSizeX = rightWall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.size.x;
leftWallSizeX = leftWall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.size.x;

rightWall.transform.position = new Vector3 (screenRight - rightWallSizeX/2, 0f, 0f);
leftWall.transform.position = new Vector3 (screenLeft + leftWallSizeX/2, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: Is this a Sprite or a ui component?

Comment: These are sprites.

Comment: Placing walls next to screen sides is wrong because they are 'relatively' placed ... you should place them in an 'absolute' fashion, i.e. the design of your level should be unique, no matter what screen size is used. Tip: post some code

Comment: Another approach if you wish to have a 'dynamic' design level according screen ratio, would be to cast a ray from player position to the other wall, the hit distance would give you a good clue about the necessary force for the player to jump out to reach the other side.

Comment: @Aybe Added some code. Can you guide me what is the best approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you design your level using the editor:*

[image]

*Then the output aspect will be correct regardless its value:*

[image]

[image]

As a bonus I've crafted you some code that lets the player stick to a wall and jump to the opposite side of it :D

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets
{
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const string Ground = "Ground";
        private const string Wall = "Wall";

        private Rigidbody2D _body;
        private Vector2 _cNormal;
        private GameObject _cWall;
        private bool _joyAction;
        private float _joyClimb;
        private float _joyMove;
        private State _state;

        public float ForceClimb = 20.0f;
        public float ForceJump = 5.0f;
        public float ForceJumpFromWall = 10.0f;
        public float ForceMove = 10.0f;
        public float MaxMove = 15.0f;

        private void Start()
        {
            _state = State.Air;
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            _joyMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            _joyClimb = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            _joyAction = Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            var air = _state == State.Air;
            var ground = _state == State.Ground;
            var wall = _state == State.Wall;

            if (air || ground)
            {
                var canJump = ground && _joyAction;
                if (canJump)
                {
                    var force = new Vector2(0.0f, ForceJump);
                    _body.AddForce(force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    _state = State.Air;
                }

                var move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(_body.velocity).x;
                if (move < MaxMove)
                {
                    var force = new Vector2(_joyMove*ForceMove, 0.0f);
                    _body.AddRelativeForce(force);
                }
            }
            else if (wall)
            {
                var climbing = Mathf.Abs(_joyClimb) > 0.0f;
                if (climbing)
                {
                    _body.AddForce(new Vector2(0, ForceClimb*_joyClimb));
                }
                else
                {
                    var jumpingOut = _joyAction;
                    if (jumpingOut)
                    {
                        TryUnstickFromWall();
                        _body.AddForce(_cNormal*ForceJumpFromWall, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnGUI()
        {
            GUILayout.Label(_state.ToString());
        }

        public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            var c = collision.collider;
            var t = c.tag;
            if (t == Ground)
            {
                _state = State.Ground;
                TryUnstickFromWall(); // fixes wall-sticking
            }
            else if (t == Wall && _state == State.Air) // jumping to wall
            {
                var wall = collision.gameObject;
                var joint2D = wall.AddComponent<FixedJoint2D>();
                var contact = collision.contacts[0];
                var normal = contact.normal;
                Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, normal, Color.white);

                // stick 2 wall
                joint2D.anchor = contact.point;
                joint2D.frequency = 0.0f;
                joint2D.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
                joint2D.enableCollision = true;
                _body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
                _body.gravityScale = 0.125f;

                // save these
                _cWall = wall;
                _cNormal = normal;

                // update state
                _state = State.Wall;
            }
        }

        public void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.collider.tag == Ground)
            {
                _state = State.Air;
            }
        }

        private void TryUnstickFromWall()
        {
            if (_cWall != null)
            {
                _body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
                _body.gravityScale = 1.0f;
                var joint2D = _cWall.GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>();
                if (joint2D != null) Destroy(joint2D);
                _cWall = null;
            }
        }
    }

    internal enum State
    {
        Air,
        Ground,
        Wall
    }
}
```

To try it:

- create a layout like the one in picture 1
- add a `Rigidbody2D` and `BoxCollider2D` to all of them
- set their rigidbodies to be kinematic **except for the player**
- add this script to the player
- set walls tag to `Wall`
- set ground tag to `Ground`

Then tweak it to your needs ...

**EDIT:**

You will have to encompass `transform.InverseTransformDirection(_body.velocity).x` with `Mathf.Abs()` to be correct, also at times the collision normal will be reversed making the player stuck to the wall, I let you figure this one :)